# How do I import a large (6 Gb) .csv file into R efficiently and quickly, without the R REPL crashing?

Tags: r, csv

I have a large **.csv** file which I need to import into R in order to do some data manipulation on it. I'm using the `read.csv(file.csv)` method, where I assign the result of the method to some variable `MyData`. However, when I attempt to run this in the R REPL, the program crashes. Is there a way to efficiently and quickly process/read a **.csv** file in R that won't crash the terminal? If there isn't, shouldn't I just be using Python?

Comment: You should also consider operating line-by-line with `read_lines` in `readr` package

Comment: My approach to running queries on very large (compressed) csv files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693819/8079808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R will crash if you try to load a file that is larger than your available memory, so you should see that you have at least 6gb ram free (a 6gb .csv is roughly 6gb in memory also). Python will have the same problem
(apparently someone asked the [exact same question for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas) a few years ago)

For reading large csv files, you should either use `readr::read_csv()` or `data.table::fread()`, as both are much faster than `base::read.table()`.

`readr::read_csv_chunked` supports reading csv files in chunks, so if you don't need your whole data at once, that might help. You could also try just reading the columns of interest, to keep the memory size smaller.

Comment: what does an implementation of readr::read_csv_chunked look like? How can I take all of the chunks I get from the large .csv and concatenate them together at the end of the program?

Comment: That is the problem, you can't if it doesn't fit into your system memory. If you really need files that large you should consider using a data base, or you could give the [ff package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html) a shot. I have not worked with that, but I think ff objects have some limitations compared to data.frames, so it also depends on what you want to do with your data whether this would be useful for you or not

Comment: OK this isn't the solution that I chose, but it's one that is satisfactory for the problem provided, so I'll check it

Comment: Sorry, R just gets  cumbersome with out-of-memory data :/ I guess the real answer is "get more ram"

Comment: My approach to running queries on very large (compressed) csv files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693819/8079808 It is a demo of using `readr::read_csv_chunked`